# Open edx edxapp and edxapp_worker not running

Tags: edx, openedx

CMS and LMS have Server Error.
I tried to restart edxapp_worker and got errors:

```
sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart edxapp_worker:
edxapp_worker:lms_high_mem_2: started
edxapp_worker:lms_default_3: started
edxapp_worker:cms_default_4: started
edxapp_worker:lms_high_4: started
edxapp_worker:cms_low_3: ERROR (abnormal termination)
edxapp_worker:cms_high_1: ERROR (abnormal termination)
edxapp_worker:lms_low_1: started
```

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/manage.py", line 111, in <module>
    startup = importlib.import_module(edx_args.startup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/cms/startup.py", line 8, in <module>
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS  # pylint: disable=pointless-statement
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'cms.envs.aws' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named validation
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: you should take a look at the supervisor error logs in /edx/var/log/supervisor directory.
cms_low_3tderr.log , cms_high_tderr.log

Comment: ImportError: Could not import settings 'cms.envs.aws' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named validation. This is in both files.

Comment: cms.envs.aws ? are you sure ? please post the error log

Comment: I have added error log in my question

Comment: which version of open-edx are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your installed version of Xblock Does not have `validation.py` file.
Reinstall it, it will fix this issue.

```
  /edx/bin/pip.edxapp install -e git+https://github.com/edx/XBlock.git@named-release/birch#egg=xblock
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used this for installing Xblock -->
https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/Installing-a-new-XBlock. Maybe I did something wrong

Comment: Frank, this error started after instaling Xblock. How to install Xblock correctly?

Comment: you still have this `ImportError: Could not import settings 'cms.envs.aws' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named validation` ?

Comment: I rolled back my server. Now CMS and LMS are working, I dont have ImportError. I am afraig that when I install Xblocks I will have error again

Comment: @DmitriiUtrobin, so now you have a working open-edx instance ? and you want to know how to install a custom xblock ?

Comment: take a look at this gist. i've been following this step.
https://gist.github.com/leninlal/d00358ad3d1db6b1888c

Comment: When I was installing, I got this error:
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'git+git@github.com:polimediaupv/pdfXBlock.git', 'at', '+git@github.com:polimediaupv/pdfXBlock.git')